# React Native: TabBarIOS, rerender tabs on click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, uitabbarcontroller

In my app i have TabBarIOS with 3 different tabs. When you change something or for example scroll page in one tab, then you go to another tab and when you come back, the tab's content is not rerendering. it stays at same place (scrolled).

is there anyway to rerender tab's content (component) everytime you click on tabs?

Comment: You can use the scrollTo method. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html#scrollto

Comment: Thanks for answer. But scrolling was just an example of what user can do in Tab. for example in first tab, there is an listview, when you click on each item in listview it goes to it's details page.
When you go to second tab, and come back to first again, first tab is still showing the details page. i need to rerender it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution in this article :
http://richardkho.com/persisting-tabbars-in-react-native/

Whenever you click on a tab, it renders a navigationios.
So when user is clicking on each tab, i should check if the tab is already selected or not. if it's already the selected tab, i should do navigate.poptotop ( for the navigation ios that is being called ).
if not, i just call the navigation